# Shutter capture functions are greyed after 21.10 upgrade

Tags: screenshot, 21.10, shutter

I have a computer and a laptop, both were running 21.04.
But after I did the upgrade to release 21.10, I noticed Shutter Screenshot Tool is not functional anymore.
All capture commands grayed, as you may notice by these attached images below.

I found a solution in issue [1353360](https://launchpad.net/%7Eshutter/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) but it does not apply to me, because I don't wanna enable Wayland.
And I already reinstalled Shutter under [new PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Eshutter/+archive/ubuntu/ppa), without success.

[image]

[image]

Any ideas? I also posted the verbose when I launch the app [here](https://pastebin.com/qR4CnEaK), to help.
I think some component was discarded at upgrade moment, but I cannot identify which of them.

Answer (score 1):

Something has perhaps happened during the upgrade process.

I have managed to install `Shutter` on a live USB version of 21.10 by taking the following steps. There is no reason to believe that this will not also work on a complete installation of version 21.10 and you may need to purge your current installation of `Shutter` first to accommodate the fresh installation as follows:

```
sudo apt-get remove shutter
```

Following your `PPA Shutter Team` link I installed the PPA

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:shutter/ppa
```

I then installed `Synaptic Package Manager`

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe

sudo apt update
```

then

```
sudo apt install synaptic
```

I searched for and ran `Synaptic Package Manager`  after which in `Synaptic` I searched for `shutter` having found it I then marked it for upgrade after which selected `Apply`.

This then installed `Shutter` without further problem and I was able to run it. It also placed the icon in the `System Tray` as expected with the drop down menu.

This at least confirms that `Shutter` is capable of running on version 21.10

Comment: Unfortunately your solution didn't work for me. I followed all your instructions, even restarted my computer, Shutter keeps greyed out. I installed version 0.99 rev 1591

Comment: well at least by process of elimination it contributes towards understanding what might be going on.