# Problems with Shutter app

Tags: package-management, 21.10, shutter

I've been using the shutter app for years and it has always worked without a problem but since I upgraded to 21.10 I have a problem.
Firstly Applications shows 2 instances of Shutter, the first, where it should be, in alphabetical order, the second as the last application added.
When I click on it it loads as before but when I try to use it, the screen goes black and when I press return, nothing happens and I have to restart the computer to get out of it/
If I uninstall it from the command line it gets rid of the 2nd instance, last application added but the one in alphabetical order remains. Terminal tells me that it is, indeed, uninstalled but if I click on the remaining instance it pops up and refuses to work as above.

Any ideas?

Comment: any help in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1373945/307670) to your issue?

Comment: If @24601's answer does not solve your problem, then please edit your Question above to include the complete output of `whereis shutter`

Comment: 24601's answer solved my problem - thank you